# Python Selenium shows OS Error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have run the following code and expected that it will open new URL(google home page) in a new tab whenever it meets condition (have to open new google page URL), but its running fine for sometime then its thrown an exception.

Here it's my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import socket
from datetime import datetime

try:


    options =webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path ="C:/Users/gsssaaaa/Desktop/Python/exe.win-amd643.6/selenium/chromedriver.exe",port=80)

    driver.get('file:///C:/Users/gsssaaaa/AppData/Local/Temp/Temp1_site.zip/site/index.html')

    time.sleep(30)

    ticketopened = False
    while True:

        if driver.find_element_by_class_name('custom-select').text == "Ready":
            time.sleep(0.5)

            if driver.find_element_by_class_name('custom-select').text == "Talking":
                if ticketopened == False:

                    window = 0
                    driver.execute_script("$(window.open('https://www.google.com'))")
                    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[window])
                    window = window + 1

                    ticketopened = True
                    continue
                else:
                    ticketopened = False
            else:
                continue
        else:
            continue

except Exception as e:
    print('Exception Occured: ',e)
    print('Time and Date: '+str(datetime.now())[0:19])
```

Here is my error message:

> OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address
>   (protocol/network  address/port) is normally permitted

I am not really aware of ports. If it's regarding port issue, then could you please tell me how to use ports in python and where to use it in my code to avoid this exception.

Can you help me on this?

Comment: Try using `Firefox webdriver`. That may solve your problem. I remember reading somewhere that Chrome allows usage of only 1 port. That is what this looks like.

Comment: Hi, in my case I am using a particular link and I can't open that link in any other browser except Chrome. is there any other way to fix it.

Comment: Found similar case here : [Webdriver opens thousands of connections](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/3457)

Comment: In the threads : `For anyone who is running into the same issue on Windows, I was able to "solve" it temporarily by setting TcpTimedWaitDelay value in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\ to 30 as decimal. Basically it terminates closed TCP connection after 30 seconds instead of 4 minutes (which is the default on Windows).`

Comment: That's about it. I don't have time to go deeper into it, but overview of this seems to be a `Chromedriver` related issue. Try if possible to close the `Sockets` once used. Or just shift to other drivers if possible.

Comment: You are starting chromedriver on port 80, which usually used by http protocol. Change it to something neutral like 5858 - ` driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path ="C:/Users/gsssaaaa/Desktop/Python/exe.win-amd643.6/selenium/chromedriver.exe",port=5858)` or try to not specify port as option. Please, write if it helped or not

Comment: I have changed my browser from chrome to firefox and seems like working fine so far. thanks, guys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a little gap in handling of the windows. To open a new tab/window and switch to it induce a bit of `WebDriverWait` and next use the index to switch to the new window. Here is the sample code block to open `https://www.google.co.in`, print the `Page Title`, click on `Gmail` link and open it in a new Tab and `switch_to` the new tab/window and finally print the `Page Title`:

```
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Gmail')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].target="_blank";', link)
link.click()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
wait.until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
wait.until(EC.title_contains("Gmail"))
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
```